# HP 840 G1 and dual graphic card

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, 22.04, laptop, hp

I would like to try to put Kubuntu 22.04 or 22.10 on my Elitebook 840 G1. The laptop has 2 video cards:
-Integrated INTEL
-AMD 8750M

In Windows does the automatic switch between the cards happen, in Linux how does the management work?

Would it be okay even if the integrated Intel always works and the AMD stays off

I need some drivers for the Intel or AMD?

Comment: I need to try, thanks

Comment: Ok thanks, with Switcheroo I see that the laptop keeps the intel processor's integrated GPU active and not the AMD 8530.
I will now open a dedicated thread on why it doesn't switch when I run a 3D benchmark